# How can I access a facebook user's subscriptions through the open graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook introduced the Subscribe button in September '11.

The subscription connection seems to live somewhere in between the Like relationship and the friendship.

Both my likes and my friends are available to through the open graph -

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?(access_token)` 
and 
`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?(acces_token)`

But public figures to whom I am subscribed do not show up in either of these responses. There is a subscription connection type, but that concerns an app receiving real-time updates about it's users.

How can I access a user's subscriptions through the open graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't looked at the docs for this

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribers and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribedto

The permission you need is `user_subscriptions` or `friends_subscriptions`

Comment: Thanks. Could have gone without the condescension though.

Comment: I don't mean to be too rude here, but to be fair, it's listed on the 'User' documentation